# Why can't Kovu defend his "not guilty" plea?

Tags: character, the-lion-king-ii-simbas-pride

That is something that has bothered me for years, ever since I first watched *The Lion King II: Simba's Pride*.

In the scene that precedes the [Exile](http://lionking.wikia.com/wiki/Kovu%27s_exile), there are 2 big proofs that Kovu was not taking part on the ambush to kill the king:

> 1) Simba was the one leading the way through the suffered land,

and

> 2) Kovu clearly fought beside the King, defending him from the attackers.

Kovu is shown to be smart, cunning and a fast-thinker -- one of the reasons why Scar himself chose him to be his successor.

Why then didn't Kovu try to use these arguments after stating that he was not guilty?

Comment: Kovu knew Simba is such an illogical person